# @ only supresses a message, not a control flow

Tags: php

I've found the following example on PHP manual site:

`Some might think that trigger_error is like a throw() or an err.raise construction, and @ works like catch(){} one - in fact it's NOT.`

```
function badgirl(){
    trigger_error("shame on me",E_USER_ERROR);
    return true;
}

$sheis = @badgirl();
echo "You will never see this line - @ only supress message, not a control flow";
```

1) Can anyone please explain me why the last line will not be displayed? Is it because `E_USER_ERROR` breaks script execution?

2) What if I registered my custom error handler with `set_error_handler` and didn't do `exit` or `die` in it would the last line be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That error breaks the execution, with `@` - silently, because `E_USER_ERROR` is a fatal error. Try running that example without error suppression operator - it will print:

   PHP Fatal error:  shame on me in /tmp/test.php on line 3

   Fatal error: shame on me in /tmp/test.php on line 3

[more on error constants here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

2. Sure, custom error handler can decide to continue execution.

Comment: Thanks, if _E_USER_ERROR is a fatal error_ - then I presume that custom error handler won't catch it (since it doesn't catch fatal errors). I would need to use `register_shutdown_function` with the `error_get_last()` to catch it. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, you are wrong. :) An `E_ERROR` cannot be caught, an `E_USER_ERROR` can (interestingly enough).

Comment: @deceze, thanks :). It seems that there is some mess with PHP errors types. I can't figure out the classification of errors. Do you know any good read about the matter? Is [this](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) the best what there is?

Comment: @Maximus look here about the details on `set_error_handler` http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, the reason why the program will halt is that you're triggering an `E_USER_ERROR`, which by default stops the application. If you'd trigger an `E_USER_WARNING` or lesser error the program would continue.
2. Yes, a custom error handler can catch an `E_USER_ERROR` and decide to *not* `die`.